# After shuffling an array to the point where it matches the original, why does equating them return false?

Tags: c#, arrays, shuffle

Consider the following method of shuffling, given an array of objects `a`

1. Take the first element from `a` and place it into `b`. Consider the index of this element inside `b` to be `x`.
2. Place the second element from `a` and place it in front of `b[x]`, so that it is now in position `b[x-1]`
3. Place the third element from `a` and place it behind `b[x]`, so that it is now in position `b[x+1]`
4. Place the fourth element from `a` and place it in front of b[x - 1], so that it is now in position `b[x-2]`
5. Place the firth element from `a` and place it behind `b[x+1]` so that it is now in position `b[x+2]`
6. Repeat this process until `b` has all of the elements from `a` in it in this new shuffled order.

I wrote some code which does this, shown below. It will continuously shuffle the array in the above process until the shuffled array matches the original array, and then return the number of shuffles.

```
public class BadShuffler
{
    public BadShuffler(object[] _arrayToShuffle)
    {
        originalArray = _arrayToShuffle;
        Arrays = new List<object[]>
        {
            originalArray
        };
    }

    private object[] originalArray;
    private int count;
    public List<object[]> Arrays { get; set; }

    public int Shuffle(object[] array = null)
    {
        if (array == null)
            array = originalArray;

        count++;
        object[] newArray = new object[array.Length];
        bool insertAtEnd = false;
        int midpoint = newArray.Length / 2;
        newArray[midpoint] = array[0];
        int newArrayInteger = 1;
        int originalArrayInteger = 1;

        while (newArray.Any(x => x == null))
        {
            if (insertAtEnd)
            {
                newArray[midpoint + newArrayInteger] = array[originalArrayInteger];
                newArrayInteger++;
            }
            else
            {
                newArray[midpoint - newArrayInteger] = array[originalArrayInteger];
            }

            originalArrayInteger++;
            insertAtEnd = !insertAtEnd;
        }

        Arrays.Add(newArray);
        return (newArray.All(x => x == originalArray[Array.IndexOf(newArray, x)])) ? count : Shuffle(newArray);
    }
}
```

While not being the prettiest thing in the world, it does the job. Example shown below:

> Shuffled 6 times.
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
>
> 6, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5
>
> 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 3
>
> 3, 6, 1, 5, 4, 2
>
> 2, 5, 6, 3, 1, 4
>
> 4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

However, if I give it an array of `[1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6]` it ends up throwing a StackOverflowException. When debugging, however, I have found that it does actually get to a point where the new shuffled array matches the original array, as shown below.

[image: Matching arrays Visual Studio Watch window screenshot]

This then goes on to call `Shuffle(newArray)` again, even though all values in the array match each other.

What is causing this? Why does the Linq query `newArray.All(x => x == originalArray[Array.IndexOf(newArray, x)])` return false?

Here is a [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yd0eMT) link, which includes the code I used to print out the result(s)

Comment: You do know this is not a random shuffle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing `object`s. `object`s are compared using referential equality with `==`, not value equality. Your example uses numbers, but those numbers are boxed to an `object` implicitly due to the way your code is laid out.

To avoid this, you should use the `.Equals()` function (when comparing Objects).

```
newArray.All(x => x.Equals(originalArray[Array.IndexOf(newArray, x)]))
```

You should also use generics in your class instead of littering `object[]` everywhere to ensure type safety - unless one of your aims with this shuffler is to allow the shuffler to shuffle arrays of mixed types (which seems doubtful since it would be hard to extract any useful information out of that).

Note that this behaviour is exhibited whenever you are comparing reference types; one way to only allow *value* types to be passed to your structure (i.e, only primitive values that can be compared by value equality rather than referential equality) is to use the `struct` generic constraint. As an example:

```
class BadShuffler<T> where T : struct
{
    public bool Shuffle(T[] array)
    {
        ...
        return newArray.All(x => {
            var other = originalArray[Array.IndexOf(originalArray, x)];
            return x == other;
        });
    }
}
```

This would work as you expect.

`SequenceEqual` as mentioned in the comments is also a good idea, as your `.All()` call will say that `[1, 2, 3]` is equal to `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, but `[1, 2, 3, 4]` will not be equal to `[1, 2, 3]` - both of these scenarios are incorrect and more importantly not commutative[1], which equality operations should be.

Just make sure you implement your own EqualityComparer if you go beyond using `object[]`.

That said, I think you want to use a combination of both approaches and use `SequenceEqual` with my approach, unless you need to shuffle objects (I.e,  a Deck of Cards) rather than numbers?

---

As a side note, I would generally recommend returning a *new*, shuffled `T[]` rather than modifying the original one in-place.

[1]: Commutative means that an operation done one way can be done in reverse and you get the same result. Addition, for example, is commutative: you can sum 1, 2 and 3 together in any order but the outcome will always be 6.